# Modifying asp.net object properties using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a asp.dropdown list set enabled=false, is it posible to modify through javascrip to enabled=true? This should happen after a Textbox has a value in it.

Comment: Yes, with the `disabled` property: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_select_disabled.asp

Comment: If you need more help please provide the html

Comment: This is the ASP tag
<asp:DropDownList ID="PrsPlzDdl" runat="server" Enabled="false" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="PrsPlzDdl_SelectedIndexChanged" Width="100%" Height="66%">

and I was trying to modify it by Javascrip with:

document.getElementById("PrsPlzDdl").disable = true;

Using a keyup event on a differente asp control. Textbox to be exact

Comment: I'm a first timer in Stackoverflow I apologize for not formmatting the last comment. ☺'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean Enabled="False"? If so, no you cannot - you must do this from the code behind. You are getting the server attributes and client attributes confused. Enabled is not the same as disabled for the client side. You cannot change the server variable Enabled on a runat="server" tag.

Comment: Good answer. I thought about the effect on the button, and did not consider the `Enabled` property itself, as I should have done.

Comment: Thanks now I understand why my code was not working. I did not know there were two sets of attributes, I thought they were just called different. Any way gotta re-write code, different approach needed.

Comment: No problem I also found (and still find) Web Forms confusing at times. I welcome the day where I can work exclusively in MVC & MVVM architectures  :)